# Permutations of multiple arrays

Tags: ruby

Currently I can get all permutations of a two item array as such:

```
[[:a, :b], [:c, :d]].reduce(&:product)
# => [[:a, :c], [:a, :d], [:b, :c], [:b, :d]]
```

However when I try and do the same for a three item array I do not get the desired result:

```
[[:a, :b], [:c, :d], [:e, :f]].reduce(&:product)
# => [[[:a, :c], :e], [[:a, :c], :f], [[:a, :d], :e], [[:a, :d], :f]]
```

The expected result is:

```
[[:a, :c, :e], [:a, :c, :f], [:a, :d, :e], [:a, :d, :f] ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [[:a, :b], [:c, :d], [:e, :f]]
data[0].product(*data[1..-1])
# => [[:a, :c, :e], [:a, :c, :f], [:a, :d, :e], [:a, :d, :f], [:b, :c, :e], [:b, :c, :f], [:b, :d, :e], [:b, :d, :f]]
```

and you can extend your data with more arrays

Comment: Or if your data is not stuck in one large array: `a1.product(a2, a3, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Since each item, such as `[[:a, :c], :e]` is almost correct it can be flattened:

```
[[:a, :b], [:c, :d], [:e, :f]].reduce(&:product).map(&:flatten)
# => [[:a, :c, :e], [:a, :c, :f], [:a, :d, :e], [:a, :d, :f] ...]
```

Comment: Absolutely genius